# data gets repeated when input to text file

Tags: php, text

i have a problem when inserting data into a text file, the data gets repeated & doesn't create newlines.
this is my code:

```
<?php
$id = trim(strip_tags($_GET['id']));
$myfile = fopen("../../asset/Timeline/Logline.txt", "a") or die("file tidak ditemukan");
$tgl=date('d/m/Y');
$jam=date('H:i:s');
$slnmdl="select nama from $tabname where ID='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $slnmdl);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$nmdl = $row['nama'];
$log_content="$tgl|$jam|menghapus data $nmdl \n";
fwrite($myfile, $log_content);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

viewer.php

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("Timeline/Logline.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('|', $line_of_text);
    $lna=$parts[0];
    $lnb=$parts[1];
    $lnc=$parts[2];
    echo "$lna $lnb $lnc <br>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

output

```
12/08/2022 14:00:59 menghapus data eWF5YW5n
12/08/2022 14:00:59 menghapus data
```

Logline.txt

```
12/08/2022|14:00:59| menghapus data eWF5YW5n 12/08/2022|14:00:59| menghapus data
```

please help me find the fault

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: How are you viewing the file? What do you expect in the file? `\n` won't be rendered as new line in a browser. By `data gets duplicated` do you mean `menghapus data` appears twice, or both lines are double

Comment: I don't see any way this script could be doing that. Are you sure the log file was empty before the script ran? Are there any other scripts writing to the same log file?

Comment: Also do you loop the fetch? This should only output 1 line as it currently is written

Comment: I'd probably do something like https://3v4l.org/u19RH for writing and then maybe https://3v4l.org/cPaNS for outputting logs. Might want to use PHP_EOL as well instead of `\n` to ensure using proper line endings

Comment: @user3783243 appears twice in one line